# Material-ui/pickers: Hide the label

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

By default if nothing was picked label will be placed as placeholder(like in screenshot bellow). [image]

```
<KeyboardDatePicker InputAdornmentProps={{
          position: 'start'
        }}
/>
```

Is there a way to shrink the label and keep placeholder empty? I tried adding InputAdornmentProps={{position: 'start'}} and it helped(in a screenshot bellow) except I do not need the icon to be at start, I need it to keep as it is, on right.
Is there a way to achieve it? I am using KeyboardDatePicker  from https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any prop not recognized by the pickers and their sub-components are passed down to material-ui TextField component.

So what you need to do is simply add the required props from the `TextField` component to shrink the label. The result would look like this:

```js
<KeyboardDatePicker InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} />
```